# Why is this code not working for mcp3008? (from official adafruit site)

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi-zero

I'd like some help to debug the example code provided by adafruit. I have connected a potentiometer and an analog servo motor which when using the python2 script give me values just fine. I took from this site: https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/mcp3008

Since I have to upgrade to python3 I looked into new tutorials here: https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp3008-spi-adc/python-circuitpython

The problem I have is no matter what pin value I give in the board I always get 0 values. The pin I use for mcp3008 selector is BCM 22:

I've also provided an image of the connection here:

[mcp3008 potentiometer raspberry pi zero w](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzWRf.png)

```
import busio
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP
from adafruit_mcp3xxx.analog_in import AnalogIn
spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
mcp = MCP.MCP3008(spi, cs)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the raspberry pi required restart which surprised me as I suspect it's because I installed the adafruit packages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).